# Play Framework: Where to put Common Templates

Tags: playframework

I'm wondering where to put common HTML templates in a multi-project Play application. Each project might display web pages or send emails... and these should always have the same style, i.e. all projects should use the same `main.scala.html` or `email.scala.html` templates but I guess without replicating them in every project.

I could put these common templates in the main project... but I don't like having sub-projects that depend on the main project. Another solution could be to create a `common` sub-project used by all other projects... Anyway, what's the usual way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a project with my common templates that is published in our maven server so i have only to put the dependency in my new projects.